# "sowohl" ohne "als auch"

Tags: usage, sentence-structure

Ich bin letztens über einen Satz gestolpert, der nach meinem Sprachverständnis falsch wirkte.
Ich kann den Satz leider nicht mehr finden, aber er lautete in etwa so:

> Daraus lässt sich schließen, dass sich sowohl A und B erhöhen.

Ist der obere Satz so korrekt? Oder muss man das `und` durch ein `als auch` ersetzen?

Wenn der obere Satz nicht korrekt ist noch eine Zusatzfrage: Ist es möglich `sowohl` in einem Satz zu verwenden, ohne `als/wie auch` oder `sowie` zu benutzen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Laut Duden – *Richtiges und gutes Deutsch* folgt in der mehrteiligen Konjunktion auf *sowohl* gewöhnlich *als auch:*

> Er beherrscht sowohl Englisch als auch Französisch.
>
> Sie bereiste sowohl Südamerika als auch Australien.

Anstelle von *als auch* kann auch *wie auch* verwendet werden:

> Er beherrscht sowohl Englisch wie auch Französisch.
>
> Sie bereiste sowohl Südamerika wie auch Australien.

Als Entsprechungen von *als auch* und *wie auch*  können auch bloßes *als* bzw. *wie* eingesetzt werden:

> Sowohl der Vater wie die Mutter war überrascht.
>
> Das mussten sowohl seine Freunde wie seine Feinde anerkennen.

Solche Sätze werden allerdings in der Regel stilistisch besser, wenn *sowohl* weggelassen wird:

> Das mussten seine Freunde wie seine Feinde anerkennen.

Die Verbindung von *sowohl* mit *sowie* oder *und* ist nicht korrekt:

> <s>Sowohl der Bürgermeister sowie der Stadtpräsident waren erschienen.</s>
> Sowohl der Bürgermeister als [auch] der Stadtpräsident waren erschienen.
> Sowohl der Bürgermeister wie [auch] der Stadtpräsident waren erschienen.
>
> <s>Er hatte sowohl die Koffer gepackt und ein Taxi bestellt.</s>
> Er hatte sowohl die Koffer gepackt als auch ein Taxi bestellt.
> Er hatte sowohl die Koffer gepackt wie auch ein Taxi bestellt.

Comment: "Sowohl ... als ..." klingt sehr merkwürdig. Meines Erachtens muss man "auch" mitanführen. Da klingt sogar "Sowohl ... und ..." besser.